# Declare variable name dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In JavaScript I want to make a function which takes an argument and in this function a variable will be created whose name will be the value of the argument.
For example if user pass "jack" in the argument then in function I want a variable whose name is jack like:

```
var jack = "";
```

Comment: Why ? What do you want to do next ?

Comment: Could you explain the use-case?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Variable" Variables in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: You want this *variable* defined in the what scope?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you won't need to do this. As **Bergi** pointed out, a local variable would usually suffice. However, in the event that you do need to use this technique, you could give the property to the `window` object:

```
function setVariable(userPassedString);
    window[userPassedString] = "";
}
```

Don't use `eval` for this, ever, no matter how tempted you are to.

Comment: And dont use the global object for this, ever, no matter how tempted you are :-)

Comment: Do you have another solution, Bergi?

Comment: Tbh, `window` isn't that much better.

Comment: @Elliot: It depends on the exact use case (which OP did not give), but usually a local object will suffice.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is there another, better method? @Bergi, I don't know enough to tell the OP what he should and shouldn't do, so I'm just telling him how to do what he asked.

Comment: @Elliot: Then first comment on his question and ask what you need to know for a proper answer, instead of proposing a solution that likely does not fit his needs. You hardly ever need dynamic global variables with unknown names. (not my downvote btw)

Comment: That'd be a good first step, but two comments of that nature had already been posted, and neither received an answer. My doing so as well would have been redundant...

Comment: Is it safe to use window[] object? public mentioned that using `eval` creates `security holes`, how safe is it using `window` object?

Answer (score 1):

Creating local variables via a function is typically a bad idea. You could accomplish something similar by passing a local object around, e.g.

```
function setVar(o, name, value)
{
    o[name] = value;
}
```

Then, inside your local scope:

```
var o = {};

setVar(o, 'jack', 123);

// o.jack contains 123
```

In this way, if the need would really arise (this is rarely required) to introduce global variables in this manner, you can always call the function like this:

```
setVar(window, 'jack', 123);
// now window.jack == jack == 123
```

Answer (score 1):

The best that you can do about is to create an object and assigns the variable name to the keys of the created object like this -

```
var myvar={};
function create(var){
    myvar[var]='values';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent using the `window` global array, you can create a local array which holds your variables.

```
function doSomething(var) {
  var vars = {};
  vars[var] = value;
}
```

Comment: vars = array();  'vars' is set on global scope

Comment: This is not valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a dictionary. Here is a very simple stub:

```
function Dictionary(){
    var container = {};

    this.set = function(key, value){
        container[key]  = value;
    }

    this.get = function(key){
        return container[key];
    }
}

var vars = new Dictionary();
vars.set('foo', 'foo rocks');
vars.set('bar', 'bar rocks too');

console.log(vars.get('foo'));
console.log(vars.get('bar'));
```